# How to filter dataframe by column which contains lists in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

With query:

```
    SELECT 
      value,
      type
    FROM dt
```

I get:

```
value   type
12     [increase, upload]
12     [increase, download]
12     [decrease, delete]
```

I want to get values which have 'upload' in column type. However this:

```
    SELECT 
      value,
      type
    FROM dt 
    WHERE type LIKE 'upload'
```

doesn't work. how to do that?

Comment: Try `LIKE '%upload%'` and see what happens.

Comment: However, I'd consider storing these type pairs in separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `type` is an `ARRAY` of varchars you can simply use [`contains`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#contains):

```sql
WITH dataset (value, type) AS (
    VALUES (12, array [ 'increase', 'upload' ]),
        (12, array [ 'increase', 'download' ]),
        (12, array [ 'decrease', 'delete' ])
)

SELECT value,
      type
FROM dataset
WHERE contains(type, 'upload')
```

Output:

| value | type |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | [increase, upload] |